# jQuery File Upload done function

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I've modified the example code provided on jQuery File Upload's [Wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) My scripting works for the `add` callback but not the `done` callback. The server is getting the post correctly and returning a JSON response.

I've noticed in the source code some of the callbacks are commented out. I'm not sure if I should uncomment them or not. Or use the callback `fileuploaddone` But removing the comment did not work.

Not sure if i'm doing this correctly. I'd like the server to return me a JSON object describing the image I just uploaded so the next step of my form can link the image with a backbone.js model.

```
<form id="uploadform">
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="imagefile" data-url="imagefiles" multiple>
    <button type="#" class="btn btn-primary uploadfile" style="display: none">Upload</button>
    <div id="progress">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
    </div>      
</form>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {              
        data.context = $('.uploadfile').css('display','none')
            utils.addValidationSuccess('Added file: ' + data.jqXHR.name);
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        },
        add: function (e, data) {
            console.log('added');
            data.context = $('.uploadfile')
                .css('display','block')
                .click(function () {
                    utils.showAlert('Uploading','...', 'alert-warning');
                    data.submit();
                });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: it might help if you tell us a bit more about what errors, messages or other you're experiencing instead of just saying "it doesn't work" ;)

Comment: does your server returns you a json object or are you asking on how to do that?

Comment: The done callback was never called. No javascript errors occurred according to my console.

Comment: Guy the server did return a JSON object describing the image that it received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What got things working was using jquery.ajax 's apparently native callback on submit, adjusted code shown below.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <form id="uploadform">
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="imagefile" data-url="imagefiles" multiple>
        <button type="#" class="btn btn-primary uploadfile" style="display: none">Upload</button>
        <div id="progress">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>      
    </form>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .bar').css(
                    'width',
                    progress + '%'
                );
            },
            add: function (e, data) {
                console.log('added');
                data.context = $('.uploadfile')
                    .css('display','block')
                    .click(function () {
                        utils.showAlert('Uploading','...', 'alert-warning');
                        var jqXHR = data.submit()
                            .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                console.log('Done');

                                console.log('e:' + e);
                                console.log('results:' + result );
                                console.log('results.id:' + result.id );
                                console.log('textStatus:' + textStatus );               
                                console.log('jqXHR:' + jqXHR );

                                data.context = $('.uploadfile').css('display','none')
                                utils.showAlert('Success','the file uploaded successfully','alert-success');
                                // utils.addValidationSuccess('Added file: ' + data.jqXHR.name);
                            })
                            .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                 utils.showAlert('Error','...', 'alert-error');
                            });
                    });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this code.

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
              alert("done");
        }     
    });
});
```

Just with not setting the dataType, the done callback is now executed ...
Code below just work ...

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            done: function (e, data) {
                  alert("done");
        }     
    });
});
```

The server return some json.